# module not found error when running the npm start command

Tags: npm-start

I successfully installed the node js globally in my machine but when running the localhost its not working. i also tried reinstalling it several but didn't worked.

when running the npm start the following error has came up.

anyone please tell me how to solve this. thanks in advance

[Output of the npm start](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h0kZd.png)

Answer (score 1):

Try run `npm i` first.
This will install all necessary dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to run npm start after you go into your frontend folder: cd frontend